# Storing a big Excel table into array with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel table with about 50 columns and over 6000 rows.

I found the following solution to read the data:
https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c

It uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read the file.

Sadly, it is really slow. Reading a file with only 50 rows allready take about a minute. I never finished loading the 6000 row file.

I then thought about using csv, but the table contains , and ; so this won't be an option.

Can anyone suggest another method?

Comment: Which Excel format will you be working on?

Comment: What does this have to do with `storing Excel table into an array` ? Why not read the Excel file into a `DataTable` and then manipulate from there?

Comment: It's xls, as the table is pretty old

Comment: @Symon I'm pretty new to C#, so only now Arrays. Will DataTables be more efficient?

Comment: Tim, C# is a beautiful thing. `DataTable`s will do wonders for you. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Symon Great, I will take a look at it. Thank you

Comment: How sparse is the table (for example, in your 300,000 cells, what percentage is full)?  Do all 6000 rows have the same "shape" (i.e., in each row, do the cells correspond to the same column/meaning).  If it's very sparse, you might want to use a sparse matrix technique.  If it's completely regular, you probably want to read it into something like a `List<TypeThatRepresentsOneRowOfData>`, where `TypeThatRepresentsOneRowOfData` is a POCO class with properties that match the columns

Comment: @Flydog57 Each field contains data and the columns allways match

Comment: You'll be much happier if you read the data into a list using a type that matches your columnar layout.  I don't know if you can mix and match the ExcelDataReader and Dapper (https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), but if you can, it would make for a very clean solution.  You can NuGet Dapper into your project.  Dapper is pretty fast.

Comment: If the only thing in your Excel file is the data, then open the file and save it as a .csv file.  Once you have that, writing to the DataTable is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from my comment-

Here is the method I use in order to read from an Excel file and into a table. You will need to have:

`using Microsoft.Office.Interop;` using statement, along with adding the correct `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` reference to your project.

---

Method:

```
public DataTable ReadExcel(string fileName, string TableName)
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0\"");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + TableName, conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (!reader.IsClosed)
            {
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return dt;
}
```

Explanation:

`fileName` will be the file path to the Excel file you are wanting to read the data form.

`TableName` will be the Excel Sheet name you are wanting to read data from.

The reason it is written this way, is because C# will read it and treat the Excel file like a database, where instead of `sheets`, there are `tables`.

---

You may need to alter the `OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0\"");`

You can find the proper/correct `Provider` here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: Thank you, gonna test that. Is this function dangerous? -> Should I create a temporary copy of the file?

Comment: _All_ this Method does is reads from an Excel file, fills it into a `dataTable` type, and then returns that `dataTable`. You can call it: `DataTable testTable = ReadExcel("C:\TestExcel", "Sheet1");` . If it would make you feel more at ease, you can absolutely create a test of your Excel before running. This Method **does not write to Excel, only reads from**

Comment: Thanks, I know it only reads :) But even them some systems "open" the file to read it and if the program crashes, the data can get damaged :)

Comment: I don't understand how to use dataTable. from the internet I found I can use: `dt.Rows[rownumber]["columnname"]` But what is the column name? Is it the same like in Excel -> The first row? Also, the program will run on a diffrent machine. Is there way to programatically get the provider?

Comment: `ColumnName` is the same as a `Column Header`. If, in Excel you use column headers on your first row, then yes.

Comment: Keep in mind that everything in the sheet your data is in will get captured using this method.  So if you have anything in the Worksheet outside of just the data, it will get imported as well.  If all that's on the Worksheet is the data, then this is a great way of capturing it.

Comment: @FrankBall , very valid point. Though, once the data is in C#, it will be easier to manipulate, I would think. Even easier if used with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to read the Excel file, I suggest [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) instead of the interop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with importing and using such code. Could you give me a keyword to google how to handle such stuff?

Comment: Use Nuget package installer. If you're using Visual Studio, right click on the project and select Manage Nuget Packages. You can search for ExcelDataReader there and install it.
The best thing about this library is that it is standalone and doesn't need Office installed.